# Delete Camera Tracking Keyframe Mid Move

Tags: tracking

I have a "decent" solve on a camera track but there is a hiccup at frame 46. Is there a way to see the camera track position keyframes similar to After Effects where one can simply delete a rogue tracking marker and the track will interpolate between the two adjacent frames? TY Joe

Answer (score 0):

You can edit the motion trackers individually and delete or edit individually curves like editing anything else.

[image: Tracking Graph]

If you have a window area set to Movie Clip Editor just make sure it's in Graph mode.

[image: Graph Mode]

Comment: Yes, I have tried that but as the camera movement solution is based upon the interpretation. of several tracking markers at a given frame it doesn't seem to make a difference or I get a prompt that there are not enough trackers. The tracker that initiates at the bump point seems fairly linear and I don't think that's the culprit. Maybe I wasn't clear in my question but is there an indication anywhere of the camera tracking path in xyz keyframes as there are in other camera tracking programs where the keyframe can be either deleted or manually adjusted?

Comment: You should edit your OP to post screenshots of your issues, so we can get a better grasp of what you're talking about.